# Jetty(9.4.12) : Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2af004b webapp/, UNAVAILABLE

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9, java-11

I'm using jetty (9.4.12) to serve my webapp on macOS (Java 11).

Although the Jetty has started, the service remains unavailable. I have used the same War file as always, but the only difference being, I have updated Java from version 10 to 11. Any possible fixes for this issue?

**Error**

```
Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2af004b{jaltantra,/jaltantra,file:///private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/jaltantra.war}
MultiException[java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/optimizer/Pipe.class, 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/optimizer/Pipe$FlowType.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/EPATool$NodeVariableType.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/quality/QualitySim.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/quality/QualitySim$1.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/EPATool.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Link$LinkType.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Control.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Curve.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Source.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Field$RangeType.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/NUConvert.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Tank.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Link.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Rule$Rulewords.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Control$ControlType.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Pump$Type.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Field.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Pump.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Rule$Values.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Link$1.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Rule$Objects.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Rule$Operators.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Rule.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Rule$Varwords.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Curve$Coeffs.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Tank$MixType.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Source$Type.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Link$StatType.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/Curve$CurveType.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/structures/NUConvert$1.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/PropertiesMap$FlowUnitsType.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/PropertiesMap$Hydtype.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/Network$FileType.class
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file /private/var/folders/s8/sgl02rb122xcl3bfc22wtfch0000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jaltantra.war-_jaltantra-any-4267422187513106243.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/addition/epanet/network/PropertiesMap.class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scanning of Java 11 bytecode was just [merged 4 days ago](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/pull/2957) (on November 1, 2018).

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2941

The Eclipse Jetty project was waiting on the release of [Asm 7.0 final](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm/7.0/jar) (released on Oct 27th 2018) so that Java 11 bytecode could be scanned properly.

The upcoming Jetty 9.4.13 release should contain this fix.

In the meantime you can either:

- use [quickstart](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-webapp.html) to generate the scanning results at build time, skipping the runtime bytecode scanning step entirely.  Some users have reported that this works well for them (and has even improved their startup times).
- or use Jetty 9.4.13-SNAPSHOT from https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/jetty-snapshots/ (until the final 9.4.13 release is made)
- Build your classes against Java 8 (until the final 9.4.13 release is available)

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait for the final release then, I guess I was too soon in moving to Java v11 :(

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened with exact error output, but in an Mule API in Anypoint Studio

> Jetty(9.4.12) : Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2af004b webapp/, UNAVAILABLE

I have identified that the cause of this issue and fixed it by adding a shared library  with the correct `groupId` and `artifactId` in the mule maven plugin in the pom.xml file, although I already specified a JMS connector dependency in the `<dependencies>` section.

What I would suggest to any similar case, is to first add the below code in pom/maven and re-test

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <sharedLibraries>
            <sharedLibrary>
                <groupId>34542e45-3432-234e-f45d-345r44533d323</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq</artifactId>
            </sharedLibrary>
        </sharedLibraries>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For me it is mule-maven-plugin. I am not sure which webApp your platform is dependent on. So, place your sharedLibrary accordingly.